# Is there any reason for this javascript to not be able to change the "src" attribute on my IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I'm learning basic HTML and javascript (sorry if this is the wrong topic) and I'm trying to make a basic website where users enter a website url, and then an IFrame appears with that website. I'm very new to HTML so this is probably something stupid, but I can't seem to find what it is. What confuses me is that this code works out of the function, though it is active immediately and therefore useless. thanks for any help!

```html
<iframe src="" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>

<form onSubmit="setIframe()">
URL: <input type="text" name="urlbox" id="urlbox"> <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>

<script>
function setIframe()
    {
  var url = document.getElementById("urlbox").value;
  document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src","testwebsite.com");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: what errors do you see in your developer tools console - also, submitting a form loads a new page, unless you *prevent* the *Default* submit action

Comment: debugging 101 - browser developer tools console and network tabs - these will show you what is "happening" when you click "go"

Comment: You don't need to use `.setAttribute()` to set the "src" property - set the property on the `<iframe>` DOM node directly.

Comment: because submiting a form submits the page. submitting the page resets the page. Iframe goes back to what was set.

Comment: @Pointy so as blablabla.src = "website.com"? I tried that, and it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: submitting a `form` usually results in reloading the page or redirecting. To prevent this, you can call `event.preventDefault()`.

Also, you don't need to use `setAttribute`, setting the `src` is sufficient.

```js
function setIframe(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = document.getElementById("urlbox").value;
  document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/q6EoRBvdVPQ";
}
```

```html
<iframe src="" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>

<form onsubmit="setIframe(event)">
  URL:
  <input type="text" name="urlbox" id="urlbox">
  <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

**[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gapuwu/edit?html,js,output)**.

Keep in mind that a lot of sites disallow embedding their pages in an iFrame.

Comment: @user5513125 Did this help at all?